# Beginning ruby Peter Cooper 1.9 chapter 7 require load error

Tags: ruby, require

I get the error below when I require another file. I am running ruby ver. 2.0.0, although the book uses 1.9. I am wondering if this is version compatible problem, or gem issue?

code in file:
require 'string_extensions'
puts "This is a test".vowels.join('_')

Error message when I run it. 
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- string_extensions (LoadError)from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from vowel_test.rb:1:in `'

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.11
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/abdul/.gem/specs

  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - universal-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:

  - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - /Users/abdul/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /sbin
  - /usr/local/git/bin
  - /Users/abdul/.rvm/bin

Comment: where is the `string_extensions` file? By default `require` will look for this file in the `$LOAD_PATH` with an extension like `.rb`, `.so`, `.dll`, etc.. If this file is not located in one of those directories you will need to use `require_relative` or give the full path to the file. To see your load path you can run `ruby -e 'puts $:'`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Your solution worked perfectly, both on Mac and Nitrous.io IDE.